# Can we use angular 7 routing after integrating with AEM 6.5?

Tags: angular, aem-6

I have integrated AEM 6.5 with the angular 7.

After Integrating what i understood that, angular components will be used just for rendering by mapping the component of AEM to Angular.

We define the components to load in the AEM page, and those will be loaded from angular.

So, can we use the angular routing instead of defining in the AEM page's ?

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    matcher: AemPageMatcher,
    component: PageComponent,
    resolve: {
      path: AemPageDataResolver
    }
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home.html',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
    {
    path: 'login',
    component: HeaderComponent,
    children: [{
      path: '',
      component: LoginComponent
    }]
  }
];
```

From the above routing, I need header and login components to be loaded from the angular.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Using the SPA editor you can get this done, Adobe provides the below npm modules to achieve the routing in your AEM/Angular application.

```
@adobe/cq-spa-page-model-manager
@adobe/cq-spa-page-component-mapping
@adobe/cq-angular-editable-components
```

Go through this [tutorial](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kt/sites/using/getting-started-spa-wknd-tutorial-develop/angular/chapter-2.html) for a detailed walk through.

Hope this helps!

Comment: While integrating I added the routing.. But that didn't worked.

Comment: No. I have a homepage where I need to load header and some content component. usually in angular we define what components to be loaded for this URL in routes r8. So, when I do that, routing is not even working.. If I declare all the components in   app module and define the components in aem page then the components are loading

Answer (score 0):

Can't you create a home page un AEM with the components you need and map Header and Login components also? The @adobe/... libraries will override the routes and create them from the model JSON of your page (spa).

Did you get to a solution?